# What to do with metal frame for clothesline?

Tags: metal

I've bought a house that has these metal pipes which were used for a clothesline in generations past.

[image: pic]

The house also came with a washer and dryer.

I will probably rent or sell the house in 1 - 3 years, so if it's going to detract from the value of the house in any way, then I want to leave them as-is. However, if it would not impact (or increase) the value of the house, I suppose I should remove them.

So, my questions are:

1. Should I remove them?
2. If I should remove them, do I just dig them up with a shovel, or is there more to it than that?

Comment: For me those would be a selling point! I say use 'em.

Comment: It is kind of cute, but if I actually *used* them would people think I'm weird and wouldn't escaped convicts and naked time travelers steal my clothes?

Comment: You could save energy, have fresh smelling dry clothes, AND attract naked time travelers simultaneously. This is a no brainer, keep 'em.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it haha, you make some good points. I'll keep 'em.

Comment: I'll add this: my grandma used to have one of these, but just two poles in the ground. One was cut and poured over for a new back patio. The other was cut and left with the pole sticking about 6" out of the ground. She would but plants around it and such for people to avoid it. I volunteered to dig it out one year. After forever and a day of digging through hard soil, 2 additional helpers, and a tractor to haul it out; we found out that it'd been poured 4-5' deep. Not what I was expecting (2') and not what I'd want to do 4 times over. I doubt they'd be that deep for you, but still..

Comment: Put soccer nets on them and start a league?

Comment: if they are above head height you could plant vine ivy so it grows on the wires.  or hand solar led lights. but my fav would be hang some 1950's women's underwear on em with led lights.

Comment: @Alaskaman I like that idea. The first one not the second one lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some might not like the looks; if they're not being used just dig them up. They may have a chunk of concrete that may be as deep as 2 feet.

At my last house I ran a steel wire on both ends then planted string beans with twine from the ground up. Way two many beans but it was fun.